# Common template solution for asp.net back-end and javascript front-end

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, node.js, templates

#### The problem

We have to find a solution that both the back-end and front-end can use for templating.
The goal is to make the front-end build maintainable, and have only in one format.

The front-end right now uses mustache/handlebars, and/or swig. Unfortunately, the mustache library for .Net we found was not sufficient, and as far as I know there is no swig support for .Net.

In the current workflow the back-end digests the pure HTML output of the front-end. This build is based on javascript implementations of a mustache/hbs or swig parser. Which can be both used in nodejs or on the client side. Convenient.
But the problem is, after the server takes apart this build, someone has to keep track of changes line by line. And the server side can't use the partials the front-end created. They use asp.net mvc...

If both the back-end and front-end could use the same template language for build/serve the views, that would eliminate the need to maintain two separate formats of the same code.

The question is, is there a known template language that both .Net and javascript can understand?
Or if not, what could you suggest to make this workflow, and the code base more maintainable?

Note: we don't have the resources to write a custom template for this.

Comment: Have the exact same problem we're trying to solve. The closest solution we have come to is dotLiquid, but it still doesn't quite cover our needs.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: It's been a while, but as I can recall we decided to let a dedicated NodeJs app do the static serving complete with template logic and everything, and left the .Net to handle business logic and database communication. the .Net exposed a REST API and it was the only layer between the two apps. We decided that the extra round trip over two servers worth the trouble because of maintenance.

Comment: Ah yes, for a separate project we've arrived at the same conclusion. Unfortunately for some of our CMS driven projects (client requirement) I was hoping to find an answer. Thanks for the taking the time to respond anyhow :)

Answer (score 0):

## [{{ mustache }}](http://mustache.github.io/) Logic-less templates.

Available in Ruby, **JavaScript**, Python, Erlang, node.js, PHP, Perl, Objective-C, Java, **.NET**, Android, C++, Go, Lua, ooc, ActionScript, ColdFusion, Scala, Clojure, Fantom, CoffeeScript, D, Haskell, XQuery, ASP, Io, Dart, and for Haxe

Works great with TextMate, Vim, Emacs, and Coda

Comment: I wrote: "the mustache library for .Net we found was not sufficient".